# Error en PHP, generación de CAPTCHA

Tags: php, formularios

Tengo un problema al intentar generar un texto (en este caso caracteres) dentro de la imagen para el CAPTCHA, no me imprime `$aleatorio` y solo sale la imagen de fondo `$imagen`, ¿qué está fallando?.

Este es mi código:

```
<?php

//iniciamos la sesión
session_start();
$texto = imagecolorallocate($imagen,255,255, 255);
// creamos la longitud del texto en este caso un máximo de  12 
$aleatorio = rand(0,12);
//creamos la imagen
$imagen = imagecreate(400,200);
//color de fondo
$fondo = imagecolorallocate($imagen, 117, 230, 156);
//imprimir  un texto a la imagen
imagestring($imagen,80,0,0,$aleatorio,$texto);
//rellenar la imagen
imagefill($imagen,50 ,0, $fondo);

//imprimir la imagen
header("Content-type:image/png");
imagepng($imagen);

?>
```

Answer (score 3):

En la quinta línea (`$texto = imagecolorallocate($imagen,255,255, 255);`) se está pasando como parámetro la variable `$imagen`, pero esa variable no se define hasta después en el código (línea 9), por lo que ahí ocurrirá un error.

La solución es simple, **mueve el código de la definición del texto hasta debajo de donde se pone el fondo** (si lo pones antes, el fondo tapará el texto y tampoco se verá):

```
<?php

//iniciamos la sesión
session_start();

// creamos la longitud del texto en este caso un máximo de  12 
$aleatorio = rand(0,12);

//creamos la imagen
$imagen = imagecreate(400,200);

//color de fondo y texto
$fondo = imagecolorallocate($imagen, 117, 230, 156);
$texto = imagecolorallocate($imagen, 255, 255, 255);

//imprimir  un texto a la imagen
imagestring($imagen,80,0,0,$aleatorio,$texto);

//rellenar la imagen
imagefill($imagen,50 ,0, $fondo);

//imprimir la imagen
header("Content-type:image/png");
imagepng($imagen);
```

Comment: eso es era de ordenación :)  gracias

Comment: @SergioHr Amigo si la respuesta te ayudo a resolver deberías optar por marcar la respuesta como solucionada en el guión saludos :)

Answer (score 1):

Date cuenta que Php,se ejecuta en forma de script.Tienes que tener claro que lo primero de tu código va a ser ejecutado y es necesario que vayas creando en función de lo que se opera http://www.enelnombredetux.com/article.php?article=codetip&